# Mysql - Get part of a text string

Tags: mysql, string, function, split, substring

I have been looking at examples in Stackoverflow but none have worked.
It turns out that the table that I have been given does not contain a column with the "ids" of the videos.
So I need to get those "ids" from a column called "embed" that contains an "iframe" in whose url is the "id" of each video.
I know that with PHP I can do a regex and get that value but I need to get this from Mysql to make a comparison with another table that does contain those "ids".

The "embed" column contains values of type:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed/9526128" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed/ph193842d54b87g" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And the "ids" you should get would be the following (respectively):

```
9526128
ph193842d54b87g
```

I have been testing with the "substring" function but being "ids" with variable length have been giving me problems...

Added query:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(embed, '/', -2)
```

Comment: Please add the query you've tried so far.

Comment: done query added

Comment: so the embed column contains the whole url starting from iframe as String? Is it right?

Comment: yes it is right

Comment: Ok.. let me try it out

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found a solution for my question, I do not know if it will be the ideal but it is:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(embed, '/', -2), '"', 1)
```

Where "embed" is the column where the "iframes" are located.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution which will work for **any** url in which id comes after `'embed'` word. While your solution only works when id starts after 2nd occurence of `'/'` from right side of the string.

Please try it out:

```
select @len:= instr(embed,'embed') from yourTablname;

SELECT Substring(embed,
                 @len+6,
                 locate('"',
                        embed,
                        @len
                        )-(@len+6)
                 ) as id
 From youTablname;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b84d3/5/1)

Hope it helps!